# How do you record a jmeter script/create a jmeter test plan for a ssl mobile app? Internet won't connect after setting manual proxy

Tags: jmeter, mobile-automation, ios, blazemeter, proxy

I can't record a script in Jmeter or Blazemeter to test a mobile app.
After setting up the manual proxy, started the recording script in jmeter, installed the ca certificate on the ipad, my ipad stopped connecting to internet and open the mobile app to a blank page.

I get 
Response message: Remote host closed connection during handshake
**ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy certificate**
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

How do you record a jmeter script/create a jmeter test plan for a ssl mobile app?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the setup exactly as mentioned in the above answer, and then click on the Start button in the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder in JMeter. After clicking the Start button, your device will be able to connect to the network, and you will be able to record the activity.

[image]

Let me know if this solves the problem.

Comment: I keep getting this error when I open the mobile app on my ipad. I already installed the CA certificate onto the ipad and the script recorder is already started.
Response message: Remote host closed connection during handshake
**ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy certificate**

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Comment: Did you click the start button in the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder in JMeter as mentioned above? I had the same problem, because after enabling the proxy, I used to open the AUT without clicking the Start button. Once you click the Start button, it starts connecting to the network.

Comment: Yes I had the script recorder already started, then I installed the certificate, then check ipad if it was connected to the internet and it was not connecting.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)
2. Make sure to [install JMeter's self-signed certificate on your iPad](https://www.greenparksoftware.co.uk/projects/webble/1.1.1/faqs). The file is called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and it's generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.
3. JMeter itself must be able to access the Internet, if you're behind a corporate proxy - you need to [make JMeter aware of this proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)
4. Mobile device and JMeter must be connected to the same network / [subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) and need to be mutually "visible"
5. Check out [Recording Using Apple Devices](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285377-Recording-Using-Apple-Devices) article for more comprehensive explanation if needed.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work. I don't have a proxy server. I set manual proxy on my ipad I use server as my mac computer ipaddress and I use port 8080 or 2020, but it doesn't connect to the internet when this is set before or after I start the recorder and I install the certificate.

Comment: I am on the same subnet mask 255.255.255.0 on both ipad and mac computer. I can't access the mobile ipaddress on my mac computer and I can't access the mac ip address on the ipad. HttpHostConnectException: connection refused mac ipaddress:80

Comment: I tried jmeter and blazemeter recording ways, but both can't connect to the internet nor load my app. It seems it doesnt allow https connections.

Comment: I even installed p12 certificates for my app on the ipad, but it didn't help. The app loads with a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this is included in Dmitri's [link](https://www.greenparksoftware.co.uk/projects/webble/1.1.1/faqs) above but wanted to call this out specifically since I missed it (i wrongfully assumed i had handled step 2). AFTER you install the Jmeter certificate, you have to "go to the setting General -> About -> Certificate Trust Settings and enable full trust for your certificate there as well. It’s such a weird place for that setting to be."